# ESLint needs me to move the function declarations, but where?

Tags: eslint

I configured eslint js test and installed ESLint add-on for VSC. Now eslint test screaming at me and tells me to move somewhere the function declarations. Could someone tell me where the error is, please?

https://github.com/ewaolczak/javascript-blog/commit/38776188eef93f8cbd40e9de64bf97fa20bd386a?w=1

Comment: How can we help you if you don't show the error and you don't show the code either?

Comment: 49:3  error  Move function declaration to program root  no-inner-declarations
  54:3  error  Move function declaration to program root  no-inner-declarations

Comment: link to printscreen https://www.dropbox.com/s/7bilsxj7nt9mop3/Screenshot%202022-10-30%2013.38.55.png?dl=0